# PHP curl switches between outdated (cached?) and up-to-date results back and forth

Tags: php, caching, google-sheets, php-curl

Ok, this is a poor question in terms of lack of reproducibility, but I really need some advice, so please bear with me.

I have a simplistic PHP script which is used to proxy a static CORS-disabled page to a script. The page is a "pubhtml" version of a google spreadsheet ("File → Publish to the web" option) and the content is changed from time to time. Here's the script (a simple version):

```
// allow CORS to grab data via js
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$pageUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/....../pubhtml';

// get the page
$curl_session = curl_init($pageUrl);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$proxiedRequestResponse = curl_exec($curl_session);
if($proxiedRequestResponse === false) {
    $request_error = curl_error($curl_session);
    //# deal with errors, use $request_error
}
curl_close($curl_session);

// send the result
print $proxiedRequestResponse;
```

Pretty basic, right? (what's simplified is actually I check `$_GET` to proxy one of a few pages I have but they certainly can not be confused)

Now the problem is, at some point I've noticed that sometimes the proxy responses with outdated data. And not only that, sometimes it gives up-to-date data and *after that* (after some time) responses with the outdated data back again! (showing the state of the data *older* the one it already showed before)

I know for sure the data in the spreadsheet was not reversed. I have seen the pubhtml page being up-to-date and opened its proxied version that showed me outdated data; I've tried to refresh and only sometimes that made it up-to-date.

I've tried to add a timestamp query to the url like this:

```
$pageUrl = '.....'.'?noCacheTimestamp='.date('mdYHis');
```

and also added

```
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
```

but still get either up-to-date or outdated data in arbitrary order.

This is really weird, so any pointers on why can this happen or how to fix (or debug) this are very much welcome.